# How to get the ModuleID from merge module?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, merge-module, installshield-2009

I encountered the following problem when building installer using Installshield:

```
File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.F1DD796A_B984_3DCA_A68D_6B352BDC86F3:0' for Feature 'xxx'.
```

I know I am missing a merge module *Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm*. I have found different versions of *Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm* from somewhere else but I cannot identify which module is the missing one.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370051(v=vs.85).aspx, ModuleID is an identifier that uniquely identifies the merge module. For example, if the readable name of the merge module is MyLibrary and the GUID is {880DE2F0-CDD8-11D1-A849-006097ABDE17}, the entry in the ModuleID column becomes MyLibrary.880DE2F0_CDD8_11D1_A849_006097ABDE17.

My question is **by what tools/methods, I can read the ModuleID from a merge module so that I can identity these merge modules?**

P.S. I am using Installshield 2009 for building installer. There is no information shown to identify the merge modules I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the module using ORCA and look at the Module Signature table.